# Fake User Online Counter

Tags: javascript, counter

any one assist me about the script of fake user online counter with random numbers and it will not change number every refresh reload page it will change randomly and some time the counter show up users some time show less users . like seems real counter .

i have check it but this script show every time more and more users did not show less users

[check this](http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts/counter.html)

```
<!--Simply copy and paste it where you wish the counter to appear.-->


<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
// counter - from http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts
function fakecounter(){

//decrease/increase counter value (depending on perceived popularity of your site!)
var decrease_increase=2460

var counterdate=new Date()
var currenthits=counterdate.getTime().toString()
currenthits=parseInt(currenthits.substring(2,currenthits.length-4))+decrease_increase

document.write("You are visitor # <b>"+currenthits+"</b> to my site!")
}
fakecounter()
</script>

<p align="center"><font face="arial" size="-2">This free script provided by </font><br><font face="arial, helvetica" size="-2"><a href="http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com">Rainbow Arch</a></font></p>
```

i dont want to use this script

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: i have already describe that i need fake counter with random numbers and it did not change with reload page or refresh it will change randomly .